# Asset with limited inflation

Tags: assets, inflation

Is it possible to set inflation for a custom asset once it has been locked up from issuing new tokens?

I see it is possible to create future transactions, but if the Asset is locked from creating new tokens, will this still work if the date for the inflation is set to after the asset has been locked?
https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html#pre-authorized-transaction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pre-authorized transactions come with their own signing weights, so as long as they pass the medium threshold you're good to go.

You *do* need to set them up before locking down the account though, so that limits you.

Comment: So it would be possible to lock out all transactions except for the preapproved ones? This is good and what we want. We don't need to set medium threshold to 0 to lock everyone out?

Comment: Definitely, that's usually how pre-authorization is used.

If you don't have any additional signers, you can set the account master weight to 0.
If you have additional signers, you set the threshold to anything higher than the sum of all of them.